# TikZ command with length as an argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm trying to draw regular polygons, but I want both the number of sides and the radius of its circumcircle to be the arguments of a command that draws this. Here's my MnWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}


\newcommand\polygon[3][]{
%   \pgfmathsetlength{\len}{#3}% Third argument with units.
    \pgfmathsetlength{\len}{+ #3 cm}% Third argument with units.
%   \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{#3}% Add cm or other unit when using.
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\edge}{-90+\angle}
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,#2} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{\edge + \angle*\i}
            \draw (\t:\len cm) --
    }
    -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.8]
  \polygon{5}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.See the tikz package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \polygon{5}{1}
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.See the tikz package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \polygon{5}{1}
```

I actually get that exact pair of lines 6 times in the Log Messages window of TeXMaker. I have tried using the commented lines instead of the uncommented ones, with no results.

My question then is how to pass the length I want to this command. I've tried passing this argument with and without units, and with and without the + sign recommended on page 1027 of the manual (I use version 3.1.5b). Even if I fix the length and define the command for only 2 arguments, the code doesn't work; that is, if instead of `\len` I use directly `1cm` and define the command to have only 2 arguments. Am I missing a library or an additional package to work with the `\pgfmathsetmacro``command? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the `\foreach` loop which starts several unfinished paths. If you fix this, you get a polygon.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}


\newcommand\polygon[3][]{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{#3}% Add cm or other unit when using.
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\edge}{-90+\angle}
    \begin{scope}[#1]
       \draw  (\edge:\len) 
       foreach \i in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr#2-1} {
            %\pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{\edge + \angle*\i}
            -- (\edge + \angle*\i:\len)
    }
    -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.8]
  \polygon{5}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there are much simpler ways to draw a polygon, e.g. with the `shapes.geometric` library. You also do not need any of these `\pgfmathsetmacro`s. Ti*k*Z parses the coordinates anyway.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}


\newcommand\polygon[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
       \draw  (-90+360/#2:#3) 
       foreach \i in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr#2-1} {
            -- (-90+360/#2 +\i*360/#2:#3)
    }
    -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.8]
  \polygon{5}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You don't really need `\len cm` because the default unit already is `cm`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! I see the error in my original code now, thanks! Just one question: why do you use `\the\numexpr#2-1' in the `foreach` loop? Cheers!

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo because the last stretch is already covered by `-- cycle`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think it should be possible to use `foreach[parse=true] \i in {1,2,...,#2-1}` (untested).  I should probably rename or alias this option to `mathparse`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Perhaps. In the past I sometimes ran into problems when using `parse` on integer expressions. So even if this is not longer a reason for concern in the most recent version, some users may use an older version, and `\the\numexpr` works for everyone.